# Javascript grabbing sum

Tags: javascript

I'm wondering how the following looks for a javascript Array-sum function:

```js
function sum(...rest) {
    let n = 0;
    for (let elem of rest) {
        n += elem;
    }
    return n;
}

console.log(sum(1,2,3));
console.log(sum(2));
```

Is this considered overly verbose code? For example, of these examples are much more 'interesting' and generally speaking, shorter: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43363105/651174. In the above, what could be improved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Reduce

You could have used `Array.reduce`

```
function sum(...rest) {
    return rest.reduce((n, val) => n + val, 0);
}
```

Or as

```
const sum = (...rest) => rest.reduce((n, val) => n + val, 0);
```

### Your code

But there are many ways to do the same thing and there is no best way to do it.

There is nothing wrong with your code and looking at your code I would do things slightly differently but mostly these are subjective style considerations to fit a larger body of work.

### Change the naming

- The Function name `sum` gives no clue to what it does, changing to `sumArray` or `sumValues` will be much more readable if found on its own.
- `rest` to `values` or `numbers`
- `n` to `sum`
- `elem` to `val` or `item`

eg

```
function sum(...values) {
    let sum = 0;
    for (let val of values) {
        sum += val;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

### Layout and declarations

I would make `sum` a `var` (more fitting of its use), `val` a `const`, and put the addition on the same line as the loop.

eg

```
function sumValues(...values) {
    var sum = 0;
    for (const val of values) { sum += val }
    return sum;
}
```

Personalty the arrow function would be my preferred solution incorporating the name changes to give a simple one liner.

```
const sumValues = (...values) => values.reduce((sum, val) => sum + val, 0);
```

Comment: thanks for all the suggestions! One question, for `var sum = 0;` I thought that in newer js one was never to use `var`, but only `let` or `const`. Could you explain why it would be `var` here instead of `let`?

Comment: @David542 `var` because the variable is scoped to the function. It is much cleaner to place a single declaration of function scoped variable/s in one place at the top of the function. The block scoped `let` declaration is noisy and appears randomly within the function (often the same name declared multiple times). If you keep your functions small and simple there is no benefit at all to block scoped declarations. With the exception of constants `const` which should be the preferred declaration, and by their nature need to be declared as needed within the function.

Comment: *The Function name sum gives no clue to what it does, changing to sumArray or sumValues...*  =>  sumArrayElementValuesAsOperands would be clearer still.  But still, it does not tell us what "sum" does. We can only infer sumthing is done to an array or maybe with an array, but that's not clear either. Oh, this observation assumes there's no typo of some kind; but still, it could have to do with  "Spaceman Spiff has array gun" or space cadets generally.

Comment: @radarbob The reason I pointed out the function name is to draw attention to the naming.  Without  context or abstraction the alternative name `sumValues` is an example, how, rather than what. Eg verb "sum" acts on "values".

Comment: No context - yep. A containing object tends to supply that context. But that's a little different from "what it does." Simple comment like "takes an Array of integers" does the trick. "sumArray" doesn't tell me about the calling parameters, if any.